# HTML 5 - Testing Offline Cache with localhost

Tags: html, caching, offline

My HTML 5 app is deployed on Tomcat locally, how can I test offline access?

Here's the detailed description:

I've a very simple JSP-based web app wherein I'm trying to test HTML 5 offline cache.

This is how my JSP page looks like (code snippet):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" manifest="example.appcache">
```

And, this is the manifest file:

```
# Resources that require the user to be online.
NETWORK:
/jsp/date.jsp

FALLBACK:
/jsp/date.jsp /jsp/staticDate.html
```

The app is deployed on Tomcat 6. I can very well access the date.jsp page when Tomcat is running and I do see the FF popup asking my permission to store data locally. How can i test offline page access? I stopped Tomcat but I see the standard browser error page (Unable to connect error message).

Thanks
JJ

Answer (score 0):

`staticDate.html` is served by Tomcat as well. So you need to keep Tomcat running, but after the browser has cached the website, disable the servlet for `date.jsp`.

Answer (score -2):

You're doing it wrong.  HTML5 offline is for when **your** internet connection is down, not when the server is down. If you have an internet connection on your computer, then it will try to hit the server, find out Tomcat isn't running, and return a 404 or 503 error.

If your computer's internet connection is down, then the browser should recognize that you have no internet connectivity and then attempt the fallback.

This also assumes you've coded everything correctly and are using an HTML5 browser.

To test, I would suggest disabling your PC/Mac's internet connection.

Comment: Does this means that offline cache feature of HTML can't be used with Intranet based web apps?
I disconnected from the Internet but my Tomcat is still running (remember the URL is http://127.0.0.1:8080/offline/jsp/date.jsp, it has no dependency with Internet connection) and I still can't see my cached page because 127.0.0.1 is still available.

Comment: Firefox has an offline mode. I think it's in the file menu. This should simulate being offline. Chrome and other browsers may have this feature as well. Good luck!  `File -> Work Offline`.

Comment: I don't think any of the above suggestions will test offline access when the web app is running on Local server (localhost). Is there anything that I'm missing? Any suggestion will help...

Comment: Did you try offline mode in your browser? Also, did you try putting `5.5.5.5 localhost` in your hosts file as well? As a sanity check to make sure your code works, did you try deploying it to a remote server and then verifying that these steps still do not work?

Comment: Your localhost will always connect even if your network connection is down.

Comment: @drogon - I re-read the question and my answer three times. You are indeed correct that localhost will always connect... I'm going to keep re-reading this weekend to try to figure out what I was trying to say or if I was just confused...  This was a long time ago, so I don't exactly recall what I was thinking.  Thanks for pointing out the problem here. It looks like I may have missed the important point that localhost is involved...

Comment: @jmort253 - No worries :)