# Html5 offline web (appcache) with firefox 35.0.1

Tags: html, firefox, offline, html5-appcache

I try to create an html5 offline site.
I followed best tutorials but when i test in firefox 35.0.1, it never works.

So i tried to find online examples like these :

```
https://whatwg.org/demos/offline/clock/live-demo/clock.html
http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/KidsBook/
```

but they don't work either.

When i cut my connection if I refreshed the page I get an error.
It's working well with chrome but not with firefox.

Is there any option to activate ?
Is it only me ???

Comment: I found this link without response : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753580/html-5-testing-offline-cache-with-localhost

Is the HTML5 offline really well implemented in modern browsers?
I'm beginning to doubt it.

Comment: and the "work offline" menu doesn't change anything !